# Pointer to Scanf with malloc, unpredictable results

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, scanf

Im trying to make my programme store the results of a Scanf into memory using a pointer and malloc, i want the Scanf to only be able to accept intergers here is my code. When i Printf the result it comes back with a random number??

```
int main(void)
{

unsigned int *Source = malloc(10);
printf("Enter a Source Number: ");
scanf("%i",Source);
printf("%i\n",Source);
unsigned int *Destination = malloc(4);
printf("Enter a Destination Number: ");
scanf("%i",Destination);
printf("%i\n",Destination);
unsigned int *Type = malloc(4);
printf("Enter a Type Number: ");
scanf("%i",Type);
printf("%i\n",Type);
int *Port = malloc(4);
printf("Enter a Port Number: ");
scanf("%i",Port);
printf("%i\n",Port);
char *Data;
struct Packet *next;

return 0;
}
```

Can anoyone explain this?

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%i\n",Source);
```

is undefined behaviour, the `%i` conversion expects an `int`, but you're passing an `int*`. But probably it tries to print the pointer value (address) as an `int`. You meant to use

```
printf("%i\n", *Source);
```

there. Similarly for the other `printf`s.

The hardcoded values passed to `malloc` are not a particularly robust idea, better `malloc` according to the size of the pointee,

```
unsigned int *Source = malloc(sizeof *Source);
```

Comment: Oh, duh! Thanks, @undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int *Source = malloc(10);
```

Source is a pointer.

```
printf("%i\n",Source);
```

this code is print the value's address, printf the value like this:

```
printf("%i\n",*Source);
```